# Fastest way to pass raw array into std::vector

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, containers

If I have an array of chars and I want to push the data into a `std::vector`, what is the fastest way to do this? I'm currently using a loop with the `push_back` method.

```
std::vector<char> vec;
char test[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3' };
for(size_t i = 0; i < test.size(); ++i)
  vec.push_back(test[i]);
```

Is there a way to push all the data at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass the array start and end iterators into the `vector` constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char test[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3' };
    std::vector<char> vec(begin(test), end(test));

    for(auto c: vec){
        cout << c << '\n';
    }
}
```

This will be faster than your method as it will only require the vector to make a single allocation, instead of incrementally allocating and copying as the size of the vector grows.

If your `vector` is declared before the array, you could call `reserve` before the loop to ensure that only a single allocation occurs.

e.g.

```
vec.reserve(distance(begin(test), end(test)));
```

or use the overload of `insert` taking a range, instead of your loop.

```
vec.insert (begin(vec), begin(test), end(test));
```

Also note that c++ arrays have no member functions, so calling `test.size()` is not valid. `std::array` however has a `size` member function.

Comment: I think you could use `end(test) - begin(test)` to give you the size.

Comment: thanks I was just being a bit lazy, updated it now to take out the hard coded size.

Comment: I like the answer except I was trying to make a simplified example. But I think I see the answer in your response. If the vector is empty, begin(vec) and end(vec) should put to the same spot. If there are elements in the vec already, then end(vec) would be what I want.

vec.insert (end(vec), begin(test), end(test));

I believe that is the line of code I will use.